# running sharepoint app in visual studio keeps asking for credentials

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

The IE keeps asking for credentials when trying to run the Sharepoint app from Visual Studio even if I click on Remember my credentails.

[image]

It has the same problem if I open sharepoint main site in IE and then click on the app link.

the domain is added to trusted sites
[image]

Answer (score 0):

resolved by setting IE\Internet Options\Security\Trusted sites\Custom Levels\Settings\User Authentication\Logon\Automatic logon with current user name and password

[image]